# sqlite UPDATE trigger firing on INSERT statements also?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm working on setting up a simple SQLite database to access via Python.  So far I have one basic table, and a couple of triggers - I want to have one trigger update a field column 'date_added' when a new record is added, and another one to update a column 'date_updated' when a record is later updated.  Here is my SQLite syntax for the triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_contact AFTER INSERT ON contact_info  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE contact_info SET date_added = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE pkid = new.pkid;  
END;  

CREATE TRIGGER update_contact AFTER UPDATE ON contact_info  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE contact_info SET date_updated = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE pkid = new.pkid;  
END;
```

The 'add_contact' trigger seems to be working fine... it fires when I add a new record via an sql INSERT command, as planned.

The problem seems to be the 'update_contact' trigger... it fires both when I update a record via an sql UPDATE command (as planned) *and* when I add a new record also:

i.e. when I add a new record I get this in the 'date_added' and 'date_updated' columns:

```
2010-07-12 05:00:06|2010-07-12 05:00:06
```

and when I update that record, it changes like so:

```
2010-07-12 05:00:06|2010-07-12 05:14:26
```

I guess I'm not getting why the UPDATE trigger fires on INSERT also?

TIA,

Monte

Edited to add:  Any hints on how to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an UPDATE in your INSERT trigger.  So the INSERT causes an UPDATE.  Which you have hooked with a different trigger.

Comment: Whoops!  I see what you mean ;)

Any idea how to achieve the original goals of two separate triggers, one that fires on an INSERT, and one that fires on UPDATE?

Seems like if there was a way to fire the 'update_contact' trigger on the update of any field *except* date_added, that should do it.  Just not sure how to go about it...

Comment: @memilanuk: You could compare OLD.date_added to NEW.date_added in your UPDATE trigger?

Comment: Just an update on an old thread, as I got around to tinkering with the code in question again today.  I changed the trigger code to read:
    UPDATE contact_info SET date_updated = DATETIME('NOW')  
    WHERE pkid = new.pkid  
    AND DATETIME('NOW') != date_added;  

Seems to work.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: @memilanuk I think you can achieve the same with `... UDPATE ON conatact_info WHEN (DATETIME('NOW') != date_added) BEGIN ...`.

Comment: Doesn't having an UPDATE on an UPDATE trigger cause infinite recursion?

Answer (score 8):

A better way to avoid the original problem is to use a `DEFAULT ( DATETIME('NOW') )`
clause for the date_added column in the table definition, instead of using an `INSERT` trigger.

Comment: And ensure that *no* INSERT statements include the date_added column.  SQLite3 doesn't seem to execute DEFAULT clauses when NULL is inserted for a given column.